# Can't install gcc-4.9-base:i386 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, gcc

I've been running into some problems while trying to install wine and steam on Ubuntu 14.04, and they all seem to stem from the gcc-4.9-base:i386 package.

When I run `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-base:i386`, I get this:

Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdee-1.0-4 : Depends: libicu52 (>= 52~m1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04) but it is not going to be installed
 liblapack3 : Depends: libgfortran3 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

However, when I try to run `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9` (or any of the other dependencies above), I get that the package's already installed:

```
gcc-4.9-base is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It also doesn't seem to be an issue of holding broken packages, as running `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns nothing.

I've added the i386 architecture to dpkg and tried the different solutions found online (most of which seem to be `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`), but nothing seems to work so far.